# Redirecting to specific page after Login

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have three pages in my application.

Login.aspx

Report.aspx

Main.aspx

When users click on the www.abc123.com/Report.aspx url if they are not signed in I am directing them to www.abc123.com/Login.aspx page but after they login I want to show Report.aspx page instead of Main.aspx page. Below id my code:

```
  protected String Username
    {
        get
        {
            return Convert.ToString(Session["LoggedInUser"]);
        }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1));
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Username))
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you use Forms-based authentication (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240/en) with permissions on specific pages, e.g. Reports.aspx? This should support your requirements and is a proven ASP.NET technique. You'd also avoid to have to implement the security code on each secured page again.

Comment: Hi Markus...I do not know how to do that.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226946/redirecting-to-specific-page-after-login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question and problem context, I suspect that you have a project that contains both the remainders of out-of-the-box forms based authentication and also some custom authentication code.
The short way to solve your problem would be to configure the page that the login page redirects to in web.config by setting the defaultPage-attribute of the [forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/532aee0e%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)-element.
But as this question is related to security, I strongly suggest to learn about the mechanisms of  [ASP.NET forms based authentication](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240/en). A clean approach involves:

- Configuring Forms based authentication correctly in web.consign.
- If necessary: implementing additional providers, e.g. if you want to check user accounts against a custom database.
- Securing the restricted pages/areas of your application (in the first step only Report.aspx) in web.config or programmatically.

This would also build a good base if you need to add other pages that are restricted for a certain audience.

Answer (score 1):

there are numerous articles on the net. here is a simple one - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240